# CSS or javascript click hold function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I use a jquery draggable and I wanted to do is when I click and hold the header, the cursor turns to move cursor. I already tried css active and focus but nothing happen.

Answer (score 1):

For a pure CSS approach, you might find that the CSS `:active` pseudo-selector/pseudo-element is the way to go, demo using `div:active` at: [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ovuxi3/4/)

Failing that, though, you might as well use jQuery to add a selector (I'm not quite sure whether `.click()` requires the mouse-button to be pressed *and* released, so I'd suggest `mousedown()`

```
$('#divIDOrClass').mouseup(
function() {
    $(this).removeClass('active');
}).mousedown(
function() {
    $(this).addClass('active')
});
```

Demo of the jQuery approach at: [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ovuxi3).

Incidentally, the reason that `:focus` didn't/doesn't work is because `:focus` is usually applied to those elements that have keyboard, or other input, focus. This is normally for form input elements and hyper-links (since hyper-links can receive keyboard activation as standard via <kbd>tab</kbd>, access-keys and <kbd>enter</kbd>).

Comment: This doesn't work with or without draggable in Chrome. The problem appears to be that you can't change the cursor once the click event occurs.

Comment: The jsbin demos both work in my version of Chrome (6.0.472.63) on Ubuntu 10.04. Which version are you using? Having said that, no, the cursor-change doesn't occur. Was that the only that didn't work for you?

Comment: 6.0.472.63 on XP. To elaborate, I get everything but the cursor changing.

Comment: Also, I don't think it's because of your approach, I think this or the built in function to draggable _should_ work, but it appears like a bug with Chrome

Comment: Thanks for that, I must confess that I noticed when I first put the demo together and just figured that my version of Chrome maybe didn't *have* a specific 'move' cursor, and thought no more about it. My bad...I've changed the jsbin demo now, so that it becomes 'move' immediately, rather than on `:active`.

Answer (score 1):

you can define your cursor style this way:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable({ cursorAt: { cursor: "move", top: 56, left: 56 } });
    $( "#draggable2" ).draggable({ cursorAt: { cursor: "crosshair", top: -5, left: -5 } });
    $( "#draggable3" ).draggable({ cursorAt: { bottom: 0 } });
});
```

for more info: http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#cursor-style

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the built in cursor functionality for the draggable section?

```
//The css cursor during the drag operation.

//Code examples

//Initialize a draggable with the cursor option specified.
$( ".selector" ).draggable({ cursor: 'crosshair' });
//Get or set the cursor option, after init.
//getter
var cursor = $( ".selector" ).draggable( "option", "cursor" );
//setter
$( ".selector" ).draggable( "option", "cursor", 'crosshair' );
```

http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#option-cursor

Answer (score 0):

Here's another suggestion for a "pure CSS" (not really, in the sense that we're still working with jQuery UI here) solution: notice that the class `ui-draggable-dragging` is added to the element whenever the element is being dragged. Therefore something simple like this:

```
.ui-draggable-dragging {
    cursor: move;
}
```

[Should work](http://jsfiddle.net/5ukrt/). Otherwise Robert's answer with the `cursor` option should also do.